# Clone other project repositories without getting permissions errors

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a Python script which merges content from different git-repositories. It works beautiful locally but getting it to work in Azure DevOps is a horror.

Inside the script I use `subprocess.Popen` to run `git clone --depth 1 --branch master --single-branch <REPO_SSH_URL>` for each repository

My `azure-pipelines.yml` includes the following script runs

```
- script: 'ssh-keyscan -t rsa ssh.dev.azure.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

- script: 'git config --global http.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)"'
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

- script: 'pipenv run python combine.py'
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

With sadly result in the following error message

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (password,publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I clone other repositories from an azure-pipeline run anybody got this working?

Comment: Have you configured the git ssh keys into git?

Comment: You mean the agent key inside the other repositories allowed ssh key folder? Is this the way to go here? Where can I find more information about it?

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: But I want to check out Azure Pipeline repos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that I used ssh URLs for the repository, but you should use HTTP-URLs ... simple but took a while :(

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could Accept it as an Answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT thanks for the reminder, would done this already but there is a grace period